# To Hop or not To Hop

Tags: discussion

I was just wondering if questions about different Hops would be appropriate on this site or would that have better place on home-brewing. The way I was think was more about the taste of the hops and what effect they have on different types of beer. Would those sort of questions be considered off-topic here, or as long it was about taste would it be seen as on topic

Answer (score 1):

I think questions about how different types of hops affect taste, storage time, serving temperature or any other aspect of enjoying the final product are solidly on-topic.

Questions that are specifically about production, such as which hops should be added to the mash when, overlap with Homebrewing and would probably fare better there.

Comment: @Jamie Eltringham.  I really want to help build this site and have some great ideas.  please email me at office@practicalboatcook.com  .  hey how else do I get to ask a mod a question off site?

Comment: Hey guys, it's an office email and I can easily block any spammers out there - just got some good ideas I want to put to a mod